# Не меняется содержимое страницы на React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ubuntu, wsl

Когда меняю что-либо в файле index.html/App.js/index.js и обновляю страницу (localhost), содержимое не изменяется. Приходится каждый раз заново писать команду `npm start` в терминале, ждать несколько минут и только тогда страничка меняется. Решение в интернете найти не смогла. Сижу с visual studio code, терминал через wsl ubuntu

Comment: Что у вас скрывается за командой npm start?

Comment: Запуск react-приложения

Comment: Возможно это вам поможет, хотя и прошло довольно много времени.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1499249/546238

Answer (score 0):

Есть вероятность, что браузер кэширует ответ и не запрашивает изменения.

1. Можно попробовать принудительно обновить страницу. Примерные сочетания F5, ctrl+R, shift+F5 . В моем браузере работает шифт+F5.
2. Также можно настроить браузер не кэшировать вовсе и запрашивать файл каждое обновление (зависит от браузера и лучше найти инструкцию в интернете).
3. В файле страницы html при изменениях вписывать новую версию файла js в виде `?ver=015` навроде `<script src="js/test.bundle.js?ver=016'></script>`