# webpack-dev-server не перезагружает страницу

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, wsl, webpack-dev-server

### Предыстория:

Есть проект на **react**, для сборки используется **webpack**. **Node.js** стоит на **wsl**.

### Проблема:

При обновлении файлов, **webpack-dev-server** не перезагружает страницу автоматически, приходится вручную пересобрать проект - после этого изменения отображаются.

Answer (score 0):

Долго мучался с этой проблемой, пока не увидел [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73296262/have-to-restart-the-next-js-dev-server-to-view-any-changes) вопрос на SO и решил поделиться тут - возможно кому-то поможет. В оригинальном вопросе говориться про **Next.js**, однако и **create-react-app** и **create-next-app** используют **webpack**, поэтому решение актуально для любого проекта использующего **webpack**.

### Собственно, решение:

Оказалось, что если **нода находится на wsl**, а **папка с проектом в файловой системе windows**, то **webpack-dev-server не обнаруживает изменения**. Так что решение простое - либо перенести ноду на windows, либо проект на wsl.